# Timezone зная час (php)

Tags: php, timezone

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно определить timezone, зная час. Например, 8 часов вечера. В какой timezone сейчас это время? Спасибо.

Comment: Однозначно - никак. Одному времени может соответствовать несколько совершенно разных часовых поясов. И да, ещё нужно знать не только время, но и дату, включая год.

Comment: Спасибо, буду делать иначе.

Comment: @andreymal я очень плохо понимаю про все эти тайм зоны, но например если мы в 3 и у нас 6 часов, то наверное 8 часов в зоне +2 , нет? а про день - огласен

Comment: я так понял, вытащить само название не особо получится (Europe/Kaliningrad и тд)

Comment: @splash58 Смещение (эти самые +3 и +2) являются характеристикой часового пояса, но не самим часовым поясом. Одному смещению может соответствовать несколько часовых поясов, а у конкретных часовых поясов смещения могут меняться, как это было в октябре 2014 года - поэтому нужно знать ещё и год. Смещения высчитать кое-как в принципе ещё можно, а часовой пояс и  учёт летнего времени - уже нет.

Comment: я уже понял. Но всяко Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Может удивлю, но в каждом поясе есть 8 PM.
Вот пример: http://www.worldtimezone.com/index_ru.php

Получить же можно через математику - берёшь своё время и свой пояс, считаешь относительно нужного тебе времени и получаешь пояс в котором нужное тебе время.

Comment: это понятно, а вот, имея время, в само названия timezone как? тем более время может иметь несколько названий timezone.

Answer (score 1):

надо перебрать все известные интерпретатору `php` временные зоны, и для каждой проверить время.

примерно так для текущего времени (я не php-гуру и код, конечно, очень «грязный»):

```
$ php -r '
 foreach (DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() as $z)
 {
  if (new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($z))->format("H") == "20")
   {print "$z\n";}
 };
'
```

результат (в текущий момент):

```
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Bamako
Africa/Banjul
Africa/Bissau
Africa/Conakry
Africa/Dakar
Africa/Freetown
Africa/Lome
Africa/Monrovia
Africa/Nouakchott
Africa/Ouagadougou
Africa/Sao_Tome
America/Danmarkshavn
America/Scoresbysund
Atlantic/Azores
Atlantic/Reykjavik
Atlantic/St_Helena
UTC
```

для произвольного времени вместо `"now"` надо подставить это время.

например, «5 часов 35 минут назад»: `"5 hours 35 minutes ago"`.